# Oscommerce understand div structure of subcategories product layout design

Tags: php, html, css, oscommerce

Here is my website URL: http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/

I am using the paid theme. All the files are correctly uploaded to the corresponding directories. But the problem is that the `product_listing.php` is not working properly for subcategories. If I close div after this code into `product_listing.php`

```
$prod_list_contents .= '<div class="row product-block list-view product-item wide clearfix">';

if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['manufacturers_id']) && tep_not_null($HTTP_GET_VARS['manufacturers_id'])) {
$prod_list_contents .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 no-margin col-sm-4 col-lg-3 img_ar"><div class="head">'.$ribbon.'<div class="thumb"><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'manufacturers_id=' . $HTTP_GET_VARS['manufacturers_id'] . '&products_id=' . $listing['products_id']) . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $listing['products_image'], $products_name) . '</a></div></div></div>';
} else {
$prod_list_contents .= '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 no-margin col-sm-4 col-lg-3 img_ar"><div class="head">'.$ribbon.'<div class="thumb"><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, ($cPath ? 'cPath=' . $cPath . '&' : '') . 'products_id=' . $listing['products_id']) . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $listing['products_image'], $products_name) . '</a></div></div></div>';
```

Some category working fine but the category which one already correct going to destroy.

So my questions are that where I need to close proper div that it will make corrections into all subcategories design?

The template files which is holding div structure are

```
/catelog/includes/template_top.PHP 
/catelog/includes/tepmplate_bottom.php
/catelog/index.php
/catelog/includes/module/product_listing.php
```

I am totally confused where I am missing div that destroying my template layout in some category not all

Is there any more template layout?

[here is the files:](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RpbxhZ2dMUIHiZBzXGJZydh1q473LbVs?usp=sharing)

The disturbing URL:-

```
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=137_154
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=137_155
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=133_12800028
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=133_140
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=133_158
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=133_149
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=142
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=121
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=66_160
http://swedxnew.com.swedx.com/index.php?cPath=126
```

Thanks in advance if anyone guides me proper way

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my questions by doing some form effort

just removing HTML tags from the database of products descriptions

Thanks